# Why isn't sox able to convert to mp3?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, audio, mp3

I installed Sox, i installed lame-398, but sox is not able to convert any file to mp3. It fails with the messages:

```
./../sox FAIL util: Unable to load LAME encoder library (libmp3lame).
./../sox FAIL formats: can't open output file `funktech.mp3':
```

How can i check if lame has been installed correct?
How can i get sox to find the mp3Library?

**edit:**
I did not install sox at all, it works without installing directly from the commandline. Lame was installed by following the instructions on their site:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

which results in the following files being found in /usr/local/lib/ : libmp3lame.dylib, libmp3lame.la, libmp3lame.a
Maybe symlinking libmp3lame.la, which is marked as executable, to /usr/bin would help?

Comment: You should consider telling us *how* you installed these programs.

Comment: I have the same issue. Although the `sox` OS X readme states to only place `libmp3lame.dylib` in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`, the latter of which is used by Homebrew (and I filled the former with symlinks), it doesn't work with the download version of sox.

Answer (score 13):

Brew didn't pull in lame when I installed sox. After a bunch of searching and trial and error, I figured out:

```
$ brew install lame
$ brew reinstall sox --with-lame # or "brew install sox" if you don't already have it installed
```

Now sox can write mp3s.

Comment: now there's a `--with-lame` [flag](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/22717) for sox.

Comment: The --with-lame flag did the trick for me. Without it sox could play MP3 files but could not encode them. Thanks @glasz!

Answer (score 6):

I had to do this:

```
brew reinstall sox --with-lame
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed `sox` using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). It automatically downloaded the `lame` dependency and works like a charm.

```
$ brew install sox
```

I tried it using:

```
$ sox somepodcast.mp3  -C 12 test.mp3
```

`test.mp3` sounds worse than `somepodcast.mp3`. Mission accomplished.

Comment: I don't like this as an answer to this specific issue, as it depends on a tool i don't use. And it just tells me that i could have done things another way, which doesn't help me to understand whats going on. But i like Homebrew, which i didn't know until now, thank you for that.

Comment: @marue It's the best I could do without you having explained how you installed it. Plus, it works.

Comment: Of course, i didn't want to offend you in any way. Thank you for your efforts.